# Detecting ambiguous options with Getopt::Long

Tags: perl, getopt-long

Is there an easy way to detect ambiguous options with the Perl module Getopt::Long?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# test ambiguous options

use Getopt::Long;

my $hostname = 'localhost';

GetOptions( help         => sub { print "call usage sub here\n"; exit },
            'hostname=s' => \$hostname,
          );

print "hostname == '$hostname'\n";
```

By default, Getopt::Long supports unique abbreviations.  For non-unique abbreviations a warning is thrown and the script continues on its merry way.

```
./t.pl -h not_localhost

Option h is ambiguous (help, hostname)
hostname == 'localhost'
```

I'd like my script to die immediately on ambiguous options for immediate notification and to prevent it from running with unexpected defaults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`GetOptions` returns false](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Return-values-and-Errors) to indicate failure.

Try:

```
GetOptions( help         => sub { print "call usage sub here\n"; exit },
            'hostname=s' => \$hostname,
          )
    or die "You failed";
```

Consider being kind to your users and using [`Pod::Usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html).  My own scripts usually look something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;
GetOptions(...)
    or pod2usage(2);

[actual code]

__END__
=head1 NAME
myscript.pl - My Awesome Script
=head1 SYNOPSYS
[etc.]
```